[Wix Toolset][Wix5] "You must install .NET Desktop Runtime to run this application"
I have a Wix v5 msi and bootstrapper (.exe) project.
When I install the MSI and try to run the installed application (.exe) it keeps saying: "You must install .NET Desktop Runtime to run this application" and I can't continue.
The runtime is installed:

This is installed on the pc (a part of dotnet --info):
 Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 8.0.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 8.0.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
 Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 8.0.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
 8.0.301 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

Host:
  Version:      8.0.6
  Architecture: x64
  Commit:       3b8b000a0e

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.19045
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win-x64

The Framework dependencies in Visual Studio projects are set to Microsoft.NETCore.App,
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App and Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.WPF version 8.0.6.
Still I cannot run my installed .exe application because it gives me the message that I need to install .NET Desktop Runtime to run this application.
Any ideas or suggestions? Is this a bug in Wix Toolset?

The following may be of interest: How does WIX know if it's installing 32 or 64 Bit software?

Check the 'Path' variable in the system environment variable to make sure it includes .NET runtime path correctly, for example: C:\Program Files\dotnet\

still no success

@juFO I faced the same issue and after trying lot of search and trials it worked for me. Try to include the file "yourappname.runtime.config.json" in your package if not added already. This file is a part of your release folder after you build the app. I missed this file while developing the product.wxs file. When I added a Component tag with this file it worked for me.

@VigneshG indeed found it: https://wouterstaelens.wordpress.com/2024/06/11/wix-toolset-you-must-install-net-desktop-runtime-to-run-this-application/
